# Which out of jboss & quay.io Keycloak should be used. Most discussionn online says quay.io but jboss works for me

Tags: jboss, keycloak, quay.io

Running from a docker compose file

```
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    container_name: keycloak
    restart: always
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Works for me where "works" means if I create a realm called wibble (redirect urls *) and a user called user1, when I go to http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/wibble/account I get a login prompt.

On doing the same thing for quay.io, the same url gives a "We are sorry, page not found" response

```
 keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    command: start-dev
    restart: always
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Also with the quay.io keycloak http://localhost:8080/ redirects to http://localhost:8080/auth/ which also give the same "We are sorry, page not found" response but going to http://localhost:8080/admin gives a login prompt.

Am I right in thinking that the quay.io keycloak is the later more supported one?
And if so, does anyone have any ideas what on earth is going on with that simple docker compose file?

Answer (score 3):

The [`jboss/keycloak`](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/tags) no more update. It's last version published 2 years ago by jboss.org.

The lasted version is 16.1.1
It is no more update and support. Please refrain from using it.

The [`quay.io/keycloak/keycloak`](https://quay.io/repository/keycloak/keycloak?tab=tags&tag=latest) or [`keycloak/keycloak`](https://hub.docker.com/r/keycloak/keycloak/tags) is correct image for Keycloak.

The `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak` directly a docker hub serve by [RedHat](https://www.redhat.com/en)

The `keycloak/keycloak` service form official docker hub by [Keycloak community](https://www.keycloak.org/)

**Am I right in thinking that the quay.io keycloak is the later more supported one?**
Yes you are on track.

#### API URL

Old version URL
It has `/auth` after `host IP:port`
Up to version V18.

(19.0.3-legacy,19.0.2-legacy, 19.0.1-legacy, 19.0.0-legacy, 18.0.2-legacy too)

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/{realm}/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

New version URL
It has no more `/auth` after `host IP:port`
Since Version V19

```
http://localhost:8080/realms/{realm}/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

#### `http://localhost:8080/auth/` We are sorry... Issue

I have no idea how to fix it. But I have a workaround method.

This URL can access the admin login screen.

```
http://localhost:8080/admin/master/console
```

#### Simple docker compose

anyone have any ideas what on earth is going on with that simple docker compose file?

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    container_name: my_keycloak
    environment:
      KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KC_HOSTNAME_PORT: 8080
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_BACKCHANNEL: "true"
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    command: start-dev
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Keycloak community no update for [`docker-compose`](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/tree/main/docker-compose-examples) since 2 years ago.
It support external database but old version V18

If you want to support external database and latest Keycloak.
You can use bitnami's [docker-compose](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/blob/main/bitnami/keycloak/docker-compose.yml)

This is Version 23.0.6's docker compose with [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/) database

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    command: start-dev
    environment:
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: password
      KC_HTTP_ENABLED: true
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local
```