# Validate keycloak token

Tags: jwt, nestjs, keycloak

In a keycloak context I am using Insomnia to get a token and send a post request to my nestjs app. I use this function to validate the token

```js
  async validateToken(token: string): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
      // Make a request to the Keycloak token endpoint to validate the token
      // Decode the token to extract its claims
      const decodedToken: CustomJwtPayload = jwtDecode(token);
      console.log(Date());
      console.log(decodedToken);

      // Validate the token signature (verify it with Keycloak public key)
      const publicKeyResponse = await axios.get<PublicKeyResponse>(
        `${process.env.KEYCLOAK_BASE_URL}/protocol/openid-connect/certs`,
      );

      const publicKey = publicKeyResponse.data.keys[0].x5c[0];
      // Verify the token signature with the public key
      const verifiedToken = jwt.verify(token, publicKey, {
        algorithms: ['RS256'],
      });

      console.log(verifiedToken);

      if (!verifiedToken) {
        return false;
      }

      // Check token expiry
      const currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
      if (decodedToken.exp && decodedToken.exp < currentTime) {
        return false; // Token expired
      }
      // Verify token issuer
      if (decodedToken.notes.iss !== `${process.env.KEYCLOAK_BASE_URL}`) {
        return false; // Invalid issuer
      }

      // Check token audience
      if (decodedToken.aud !== process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID) {
        return false; // Invalid audience
      }

      // Token is valid
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error validating token:', error);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Yet I am having this error
`Error validating token: JsonWebTokenError: invalid token` it's not verbose enough and I can not get my mind around it.

Does anyone have any idea how to get through ?

**EDIT:** now that both my db and keycloak are running on the same Docker, here is my app structure

```
my-nestjs-project/
│
├── src/
│   ├── auth/
│   ├── catApi/
│   │   ├── catApi.controller.spec.ts  
│   │   ├── catApi.controller.ts
│   │   ├── catApi.module.ts
│   │   ├── catApi.service.spec.ts
│   │   └── catApi.service.ts
│   ├── job/
│   │   ├── dto
│   │   ├── job.controller.ts
│   │   ├── job.module.ts
│   │   └── job.service.ts
│   ├── keycloak/
│   │   ├── keycloak.guard.spec.ts # ??? nothing is happening here
│   │   ├── keycloak.guard.ts      # guarding routes in the backend
│   │   ├── keycloak.module.ts
│   │   └── keycloak.service.ts    # Keycloak logic to discover keycloak issuer conf, validatetoken
│   ├── prisma
│   ├── webapp
│   │   ├── dto
│   │   ├── job.controller.ts 
│   │   ├── job.module.ts
│   │   └── job.service.ts
│   │
│   └── ...                  # Other pages (e.g., app.module.ts, main.ts, etc.)
│
├── node_modules/            # Node modules (not manually edited)
│
├── .env.local               # Environment variables (e.g., Keycloak URL, client ID)
│
├── styles/                  # Global styles, CSS modules, etc.
│
├── docker-compose.yml       # Keycloak Docker Compose File
│
├── package.json             # Project metadata and dependencies
│
└── ...
```

Job and Webapp are both business logic and have db tables, they will be the protected routes when I succeed. I am using catApi to hit [catfacts](https://catfact.ninja/fact) and get some fun and quirky content with Insomnia, this route is currently protected

```js
@Get('facts/cats')
  @UseGuards(KeycloakAuthGuard)
  getCatFacts() {
    this.apiService.getCatFactsWithAxiosLib();
  }
```

I get my token via : [image: Post in insomnia at http://localhost:8080/realms/my-nestjs-app/protocol/openid-connect/auth]

and ask for cat fact like this [image: get request ininsomnia]

and that's when it runs through my function above and send me back the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Explanation of the token validation logic

[image]

**Decode the Token**: The JWT token is decoded to extract its payload, which includes information like the issuer, audience, and expiry time.

**Verify Issuer and Audience**: The code checks if the token's issuer (iss) and authorized party (azp) match the expected values, ensuring it's from a trusted source and intended for the correct audience.

**Check Expiry**: The token's expiry time (exp) is compared against the current time to ensure it hasn't expired.

**Fetch Public Key**: The code retrieves the public key from the Keycloak server, which is necessary for the next step.

**Signature Verification**: Using the obtained public key, the code verifies the token's signature to ensure it's valid and hasn't been tampered with.

This code will work

Token generator by [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/)

##### Install Docker Desktop

[Install Docker Desktop in Windows](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/)

Or [In Mac](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install/)

##### Launching Docker Desktop

[image]

Save as `docker-compose.yml`
More detail information in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76914407/which-out-of-jboss-quay-io-keycloak-should-be-used-most-discussionn-online-sa/76917013#76917013)

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest  # Update to the latest Keycloak image
    command: start-dev
    environment:
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: password
      KC_HTTP_ENABLED: true  # Enable HTTP if you're not using HTTPS
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local
```

##### Launching Keycloak

In root directory

```bash
docker compose up
```

[image]

##### Open Keycloak

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

[image]
[image]

##### Check User Token

Token Endpoint

```
POST http://localhost:8080/realms/my-nestjs-app/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

At `x-www-form-urlencoded` tab

```
client_id : admin-cli
username  : admin
password  : 1234
grant_type : password
```

[image]

##### file hierarchy structure for your Next.js project

[image]

Each file code

**`auth.controller.ts`**

```js
import {Body, Controller, Post} from '@nestjs/common';
import {KeycloakService} from '../keycloak/keycloak.service';

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private keycloakService: KeycloakService) {}

  @Post('validateToken')
  async validateToken(@Body() body) {
    const {token} = body;
    return await this.keycloakService.validateToken(token);
  }
}
```

---

**`auth.module.ts`**

```js
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common';

import {KeycloakModule} from '../keycloak/keycloak.module';

import {AuthController} from './auth.controller';
import {AuthService} from './auth.service';

@Module({
  imports: [KeycloakModule],
  providers: [AuthService],
  controllers: [AuthController]
})
export class AuthModule {
}
```

---

**`cat-api.module`**

```js
import {HttpModule} from '@nestjs/axios';
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common';

import {KeycloakModule} from '../keycloak/keycloak.module';

import {CatApiController} from './catApi.controller';
import {CatApiService} from './catApi.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    KeycloakModule,
    HttpModule,
  ],
  controllers: [CatApiController],
  providers: [CatApiService],
})
export class CatApiModule {
}
```

---

**`catApi.controller.ts`**

```js
import { Controller, Get, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CatApiService } from './catApi.service';
import { KeycloakAuthGuard } from '../keycloak/keycloak.guard';

@Controller('facts')
export class CatApiController {
  constructor(private catApiService: CatApiService) {}

  @Get('cats')
  @UseGuards(KeycloakAuthGuard)
  async getCatFacts() {
    return this.catApiService.getCatFactsWithAxiosLib();
  }
}
```

---

**`catApi.service.ts`**

```js
import {HttpService} from '@nestjs/axios';
import {Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';
import {AxiosResponse} from 'axios';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class CatApiService {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}

  async getCatFactsWithAxiosLib(): Promise<any> {
    try {
      // Replace 'external-api-url' with the actual API URL
      const response: Observable<AxiosResponse<any>> =
          this.httpService.get('https://catfact.ninja/breeds?limit=1');
      return response
          .pipe(map((axiosResponse) => {
            return {
              data: axiosResponse.data,
              status: axiosResponse.status,
            };
          }))
          .toPromise();
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle error (e.g., log it, format it, etc.)
      console.error('Error fetching cat facts:', error);
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch cat facts');
    }
  }
}
```

---

**`keycloak.guard.ts`**

```js
import {CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

import {KeycloakService} from './keycloak.service';

@Injectable()
export class KeycloakAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private keycloakService: KeycloakService) {}

  canActivate(
      context: ExecutionContext,
      ): boolean|Promise<boolean>|Observable<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const token = this.keycloakService.extractToken(request);

    if (!token) {
      // Handle the case where the token is not provided
      return false;
    }

    return this.keycloakService.validateToken(token);
  }
}
```

---

**`keycloak.module.ts`**

```js
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

import { KeycloakService } from './keycloak.service';

@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule, ConfigModule],
  providers: [KeycloakService],
  exports: [KeycloakService],
})
export class KeycloakModule {
}
```

---

**`keycloak.service.ts`**

```js
import {HttpService} from '@nestjs/axios';
import {Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

@Injectable()
export class KeycloakService {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}

  extractToken(request: any): string|null {
    const authHeader = request.headers.authorization;
    if (authHeader) {
      return authHeader.split(' ')[1];  // Assumes Bearer token format
    }
    return null;
  }

  async validateToken(token: string): Promise<boolean> {
    const keycloakUrl = 'http://localhost:8080';
    const realm = 'my-nestjs-app';
    const clientId = 'admin-cli';

    try {
      if (!token) {
        console.error('Token not provided');
        return false;
      }
      const decodedToken = jwt.decode(token, {complete: true});

      const publicKeyResponse = await axios.get(
          `${keycloakUrl}/realms/${realm}/protocol/openid-connect/certs`);
      const signingKey = publicKeyResponse.data.keys.find(
          key => key.use === 'sig' && key.alg === 'RS256');

      if (!signingKey) {
        return false;  // Signing key not found
      }

      const pemStart = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n';
      const pemEnd = '\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----';
      const pem = pemStart + signingKey.x5c[0] + pemEnd;

      if (decodedToken.payload.iss !== `${keycloakUrl}/realms/${realm}`) {
        return false;  // Invalid issuer
      }

      if (decodedToken.payload.azp !== clientId) {
        return false;  // Invalid audience
      }

      const currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
      if (decodedToken.payload.exp < currentTime) {
        return false;  // Token expired
      }

      jwt.verify(token, pem, {algorithms: ['RS256']});
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error validating token:', error);
      return false;  // Error in validating token
    }
  }
}
```

---

**`app.module.ts`**

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { CatApiModule } from './cat-api/cat-api.module';
import { JobModule } from './job/job.module';
import { WebappModule } from './webapp/webapp.module';
import { KeycloakModule } from './keycloak/keycloak.module';

@Module({
  imports: [AuthModule, CatApiModule, JobModule, WebappModule, KeycloakModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

---

**`main.ts`**

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors(); // Enables CORS for all routes
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

---

##### Install Dependencies

```js
npm install axios jsonwebtoken reflect-metadata rxjs
```

##### Run it

```js
npm run start
```

[image]

##### Result

Get token first by Postman
[image]

[image]

Get Call with token.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/facts/cats
```

The response body data get from this URL'data

```bash
'https://catfact.ninja/breeds?limit=1'
```

getCatFactsWithAxiosLib() at `catApi.service.ts` file
Forwarding by this code.

```js
@Controller('facts')
export class CatApiController {
  constructor(private catApiService: CatApiService) {}

  @Get('cats')
  @UseGuards(KeycloakAuthGuard)
  async getCatFacts() {
    return this.catApiService.getCatFactsWithAxiosLib();
  }
}
```

[image]

---

##### JWKS (JSON Web Key Set)

**Retrieve JWKS URI**: The code accesses the JWKS (JSON Web Key Set) URI, a standard URL provided by the authentication server (like Keycloak), which contains the public keys.

**Fetch Public Keys**: It then makes an HTTP request to this URI to fetch the set of public keys, one of which will be used to verify the JWT token's signature.

```
http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

```json
{
  "issuer": "http://localhost:8080/realms/my-nestjs-app",
  "authorization_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/realms/my-nestjs-app/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
  "token_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/realms/my-nestjs-app/protocol/openid-connect/token",
  "introspection_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/realms/my-nestjs-app/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect",
  "userinfo_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/realms/my-nestjs-app/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
  "end_session_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/realms/my-nestjs-app/protocol/openid-connect/logout",
  "frontchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
  "frontchannel_logout_supported": true,
  "jwks_uri": "http://localhost:8080/realms/my-nestjs-app/protocol/openid-connect/certs",
  "check_session_iframe": "http://localhost:8080/realms/my-nestjs-app/protocol/openid-connect/login-status-iframe.html",
  "grant_types_supported": [
    "authorization_code",
    "implicit",
    "refresh_token",
    "password",
    "client_credentials",
    "urn:openid:params:grant-type:ciba",
    "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code"
  ],
// cut-off
```

**Define Certificate Boundaries**: The code defines the starting (pemStart) and ending (pemEnd) boundaries of a PEM formatted certificate.

**Extract Key**: It extracts the first certificate (x5c[0]) from the signingKey object, which is part of the JSON Web Key Set (JWKS) retrieved from the authentication server.

**Create PEM Format**: These components are concatenated to create a full PEM-formatted public key (pem), which is used for verifying JWT signatures.

```js
const pemStart = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n';
const pemEnd = '\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----';
const pem = pemStart + signingKey.x5c[0] + pemEnd;
```

Comment: My keycloak server is not on a docker yet, I need to fix that before trying to apply your solution

Comment: @Mowso, I updated my answer add a docker part and overview diagram.

Comment: Thank you for that, I figured out my docker and updated my question. I am in nestjs so I guess your approach is to frontend for me ?

Comment: @Mowso, I revised all of the content switching from `React` to `nestjs` and update Keycloak version from v19 to v23, and using "my-nestjs-app" realm to match your realm. But I am still using Postman.

Comment: No idea why it did not work previously but I rewrote the whole thing following your advices and it worked !

Comment: I am happy to hear you got it. Can you up-vote too? It will give me an encourage to keep answer. Thanks!